# AppFabric Distributed Cache Configuration

Tags: asp.net, caching, appfabric, appfabric-cache

I would like my ASP.NET application to use AppFabric Distributed Cache instead of In memory cache.

I have a class CacheService that uses CacheFactory from EnterpriseLibrary Caching:

```
ICacheManager manager =  CacheFactory.GetCacheManager(CacheManagerName);
```

Is there a way to configure this in web.config so that some AppFabricManager will be used instead of in-memory cache?

Comment: It might be helpful for you http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh361711%28v=azure.10%29.aspx

Comment: This is about Session provider and not cache provider. I've actually already seen this and also going to use, but the question was about something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an AppFabric caching provider for Enterprise Library [here](http://entlibextensions.codeplex.com/).